# When does hook_node_access() get invoked for $op == "create"?

Tags: 7, users

When does [`hook_node_access`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) get invoked for `$op == "create"` ?  In other words, at what portion of the node creation process is this permission checked?  I am not seeing anything in the API does about this.

I have a situation where I need to restrict a subset of users to only be allowed to create/edit content with a particular taxonomy term based on their user profile.  I have the `$op == "update"` and node form logic all worked out, and am not sure what I need to do about `$op == "update"`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets called from [`_node_add_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/_node_add_access/7), which is the access callback for the `node/add` path (see [`node_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_menu/7)):

```
foreach ($types as $type) {
  if (node_hook($type->type, 'form') && node_access('create', $type->type)) {
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

[`node_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_access/7) has this line in it:

```
$access = module_invoke_all('node_access', $node, $op, $account);
```

Which is when `hook_node_access()` is actually invoked.

To answer your question, it's called before the node add form is ever displayed to a user; obviously if it returns FALSE then access is denied to the form.